# Jest: Mock a specific ES6 class method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

```
import Store from 'electron-store';

class Test {
   private storeInstance: any;
   
   public initialise() {
     if(!Test.storeInstance) {
     Test.storeInstance = new Store({name: 'test', key:123}); // returns Default
    }
   }

   public getInstance() {
     return Test.storeInstance;
   }
}
```

**Somewhere in the implementation, it is used as like this**

```
   this.state = {
      view: Test.getInstance().get(
        this.props.objectName + '.' + DEFAULT_VIEW_KEY,
      )
   }
```

I am trying to mock like this below:

```
jest.spyOn(Test, 'getInstance', 'get').mockImplementation(() => 'Default')

get is a return function from electron-store which also has some arguments

expect(Test.getInstance().get({name: 'test', key: 123})).toBe('Default)
```

**But not working, what am i doing wrong? And is this the correct approach of mocking using third party store object?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing incorrect, the initialise was suppose to be spyed not the getInstance here.

Here is my final version of code:

```
jest.spyOn(DashboardStoreUtil, 'initialise');

  beforeAll(() => {
    Test.initialise();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

from the documentation:

> Use `.toBe` to compare primitive values or to check referential identity of object instances. It calls Object.is to compare values, which is even better for testing than === strict equality operator.

instead you should use `toMatchObject`, `toEqual` or `toStrictEqual`

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it is still not working with the expectation.